# Current location in sencha touch

Tags: google-maps, extjs, sencha-touch

I am using the following code to display my current location on Sencha Touch 2. Its showing the correct latitude in console.log() but not showing the map. Please help.

```
Ext.define('restApp.view.GreetingView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Map',
     alias: 'widget.mymap',


    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        //tpl: '<p>The ID is {uuid}</p><p>The content is {display}</p>',
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        }

    },

    initialize:function(){

        Ext.Viewport.add({

        xtype: 'map',
        id:'geomap',
        itemId:'ma'

});
           var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
              autoUpdate: true,
              frequency: '10000',

                    listeners: {
                        locationupdate: function (geo) {        

                            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude());
                            Ext.getCmp('geomap').setData(center);
                            //restApp.view.GreetingView.getComponent('ma').update(center);

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: center,
                                map: Ext.getCmp('geomap').map
                            });

                            console.log('New latitude: '+ geo.getLatitude());

                        },

                        locationerror: function (geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {

                            if (bTimeout) {
                                alert('Timeout occurred.');
                            } 
                            else {
                                alert('Error occurred.');
                            }

                }

            }

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

### OLD ANSWER

Comparing it to a snippet I use for the same purpose (shown below), I realised the issue is a simple one. "center" is a reserved word. Try using a different variable name.

PART OF EDIT: removal of code snippets.

### NEW ANSWER

I looked around and noticed your "project" is but a piecemeal collection of demo code.

Here's a complete code solution, with all excess pieces removed for simplicity, as well as over use of variables, also expanded to a longwinded format to be obvious.

```
/*
The application, including a simple launcher.
*/

Ext.application({
    requires    : ['Ext.device.Geolocation'],
    views       : ['MainView'],
    controllers : ['Maps'],
    name        : 'Geo',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Geo.view.MainView', {fullscreen: true});
    }
});

/*
The View to display the map, as well as how to include the navigation bar
and include a "you are here" button.
*/

Ext.define('Geo.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    alias: 'widget.mainview',

    requires: [
        'Ext.Panel',
        'Ext.Map',
        'Ext.navigation.Bar',
        'Ext.Button'
    ],

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype  : 'panel',
                title  : 'Map',
                itemId : 'mapPanel',
                items  : [
                    {
                        xtype: 'map',
                        height: '100%',
                        itemId: 'map'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        navigationBar: {
            docked: 'top',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'youAreHereButton',
                    text: 'You Are Here'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});


/* 
The Controller with functionality for the "you are here" button tap 
*/
Ext.define('Geo.controller.Maps', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            mapView: {
                selector: 'mainview #map',
                xtype: 'Ext.Map'
            },
            mainView: {
                selector: 'mainview',
                xtype: 'Ext.navigation.View'
            }
        },

        control: {
            "mainview #youAreHereButton": {
                tap: 'onYouAreHereTap'
            }
        }
    },

    onYouAreHereTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        // set 'mapView' as the parent view displaying the map
        var mapView = this.getMapView();

        // control measure for old browsers or denied permission for location detection.
        if (Ext.feature.has.Geolocation) {
            /*
            Ext.device.Geolocation uses native (phone) Geolocation capabilities if available,
            and falls back to Ext.util.Geolocation if only browser support detected.
            */
            Ext.device.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
                allowHighAccuracy : true,
                maximumAge        : 0,
                timeout           : 20000,
                success           : function(position) {
                    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude = position.coords.longitude,
                        location  = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                        marker    = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position  : location,
                            map       : mapView.getMap(),
                            animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
                        });

                    mapView.setMapOptions({   // Move to the center
                        center: location
                    });
                },
                failure: function() {
                    console.log('something went wrong!');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Yes, I could have simplified it further down to a single view, containing also the controller's handler for the "you are here" tap. I have chosen to present it this way to assist you with understanding the MVC pattern and how it applies in Sencha Touch.

For this to work, it'll require the Sencha Touch library, as well as this following line:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

This is the script which includes Google Maps in your page and is essential for displaying.

Learn more:

https://www.sencha.com/learn/hello-world/ - getting started

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide - complete documentation for how to do anything in Sencha Touch, starting with the Guides page.

Comment: No using other variable name is also not working. But if u can help with your answer i can get it to work. What does "this.getMapView().getMap()" do? and where i am keeping the map in this? Please explain your code. I will check if it works.